# How to see if a sub value is in masked value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bitwise-operators, radix, bitmask

I came across some code that stores multiple checkbox values into 1 value in the database.

This works by assigning each value a base 2^n value, and adding all the selected values and storing that result.

I am wondering how to query for records in the database that have a specific value inside the value that is stored in the db.

Example

```
Checkbox 1 = 2
Checkbox 2 = 4
Checkbox 3 = 8
Checkbox 4 = 16
```

Lets say checkboxes 1 and 3 are selected. We would store 10 in the database.

How would I query for records the have checkbox 1(value 2) selected in the resulting value that is stored in the database(10)?

This is sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use bitwise [`AND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE answer & 10 = 10
```

---

Similar approach used on [@@OPTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/options-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> The **@@OPTIONS** function returns a bitmap of the options, converted to a base 10 (decimal) integer.
>
> To decode the **@@OPTIONS** value, convert the integer returned by **@@OPTIONS** to binary, and then look up the values on the table at Configure the user options Server Configuration Option. For example, if SELECT @@OPTIONS; returns the value 5496, use the Windows programmer calculator (calc.exe) to convert decimal 5496 to binary. The result is 1010101111000. The right most characters (binary 1, 2, and 4) are 0, indicating that the first three items in the table are off.

Checking [ANSI_NULLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> To view the current setting for this setting, run the following query:

```
DECLARE @ANSI_NULLS VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF';  
IF ( (32 & @@OPTIONS) = 32 ) SET @ANSI_NULLS = 'ON';  
SELECT @ANSI_NULLS AS ANSI_NULLS;
```

Comment: For this example, where would I put the value 2? would it be `answer & 2 = 10`?

Comment: `answer & 2 = 2` [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=75b4470e57cf5bd948f3790cb35d1996)

Comment: interesting. I'll have to read up more on bit masking. It took me awhile to understand how these values were being stored/retrieved. Thank you

Comment: @Programmatic Same approach is used: [@@OPTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/options-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and example of checking [ANSI NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) `DECLARE @ANSI_NULLS VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF';  
IF ( (32 & @@OPTIONS) = 32 ) SET @ANSI_NULLS = 'ON';  
SELECT @ANSI_NULLS AS ANSI_NULLS;`

Answer (score 1):

you can use bitwise operation which is `&`

let take 12 as example. The bitwise equivalent of 12 is `1100`. if you would like to get whether the checkbox 3 is selected you need to compare with 8 (equivalent `1000`)

```
1100
1000
-----
1000 => 8
```

So your final query would be

```
SELECT * from Table1 WHERE answer & 8 = 8
```